# Managing non-serializable objects at the session level

Tags: wicket

My Wicket application integrates a couple of third party services. When a user authenticates to the app, one of the services instantiates a client object tied to that particular user.

Instantiating the client is quite expensive, so re-instantiating it with every request isn't quite an option. Were the client serializable, I'd keep a reference in the session, but since it isn't, I'm maintaining a map of clients at the application level, keyed by session. It works, but it's a little kludgy, particularly when a session expires or something else misbehave and the map is out of sync.

I'm wondering if there might be any other options to that problem. I was thinking along the line of intercepting the serialization of the session, and maintaining the client instances in memory instead.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use a [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to be sure to close clients from destroyed sessions?

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea! I was looking for a more "built-in" Wicket solution, but that might actually to the trick quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

### DON'T DO THIS!

As per tetsuo's comment, this approach wouldn't work.

#### Original, non-working proposition

Besides an `HttpSessionListener`, you could also use a `WeakHashMap` in your application. You can then keep the key to your client objects in the Wicket `Session`. When the session is destroyed, the corresponding key-value entry in the map will be garbage-collected automatically.

See this [explanation of weak references](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references) in Java.

Comment: The `WeakHashMap` would probably fail (or be very fragile). Since Wicket serializes and de-serializes the session every request, the session objects in memory are GC'ed and recreated. Thus, the map keys would be deallocated, and the weak referenced values would be eligible for collection.